# Prove that $(\mu \times \mu)(G) = 0$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure using Fubini

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ is a Borel measurable function. Suppose $G = \{(x,y)\mid f(x) = y\} \subset [0,1] \times [0,1]$. Use Fubini to prove that 
>   $$
> (\mu \times \mu)(G) = 0.
> $$

---

What I've tried:

$$(\mu \times \mu)(G) = \iint_{G}\  d\mu d\mu = \iint 1_G(x,y)\  d\mu d\mu.$$

I kind of get stuck here, how am i supposed to go further, is it for example smart to take the rieman integral, or can i say the following thing:

$$G \subset \{ 0\leq x \leq1, f(x)\leq y \leq f(x) \}$$ so we see that

$$\iint 1_G(x,y) d\mu d\mu \leq \iint 1_{\{ 0\leq x \leq1, f(x)\leq y \leq f(x) \}} = \int_{[0,1]} \int_{\{f(x)\}} 1_G(x,y) d\mu d\mu = 0.$$

Since $\{f(x)\}$ is a singleton...?

Kees

Comment: Fubini suggests iterated integration. Think a little about the integration order that conveniently gives the desired result.

Comment: isn't that what i am doing in the bottom of the solution. Or can i write the set G as G = $(x,y) | y \leq f(x) \leq y$, which always gives 0 if one integrates over Y?

Comment: Yes, that's what you are doing at the bottom (it would be better to indicate the variable of integration, however, so write $d\mu(y)\,d\mu(x)$ or something along those lines instead of $d\mu d\mu$). So, "yes, you can say the following thing, it's what the mention of Fubini suggests you do". Of course, you need to give an argument that $G$ is a measurable set at some point.

Comment: yeah, in the exercise i already did that so you're right on that one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $G_{x}=\lbrace y\in[0,1]:(x,y)\in G\rbrace$.  Clearly, $\mu(G_{x})=0$ for all $x$ (even a.e. would be sufficient ). Now use the fact that 
$$(\mu\times\mu)(G)=\int_{[0.1]}\mu(G_{x})d\mu(x)=0.$$